# Why the below program, without a sleep go to deadlock state but with sleep it executes all the three threads and terminates normally?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class ThreadTest {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ExampleTest obj = new ExampleTest();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runn(obj));
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runn(obj));
    Thread t3 = new Thread(new Runn(obj));
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();

    //Thread.sleep(1);

    obj.exit();

}
```

}

```
class ExampleTest {
public synchronized void enter() {
    try {
        System.out.println("printed " +Thread.currentThread().getName() +" inside wait");
        this.wait();
        System.out.println("printed " +Thread.currentThread().getName() +" exit wait");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("printed " +Thread.currentThread().getName() +" at time: "+System.currentTimeMillis());
}

public synchronized void exit() {
    this.notifyAll();
}
```

}

```
class Runn implements Runnable {
ExampleTest obj;

public Runn(ExampleTest obj) {
    this.obj = obj;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    obj.enter();
}
```

}

> what is the role of notifyAll(). Will notifyAll() allows all the waiting thread to acquire lock sequentially in random order or only one thread can acquire the lock?

Answer (score 3):

Without the sleep statement the statement `obj.exit();` will be very likely be executed before all of your threads reaching their wait status. ie. the `notifyAll` call will be over before at least one of your thread is in wait status. So at least one of your threads will be stuck in wait status  waiting for some other thread to notify it and wake up. But that will never happen as obj.exit() is already finished.

With your sleep statement in place , all of your threads will get a chance to reach their wait status and your notifyAll call after the sleep will wake them all, The order of waking up will not be deterministic and will be handled by the thread scheduler.

Comment: Will notifyAll() wake them up at once or in order?

Comment: @Paranv:  As I said, wake up never going to be in any particular order. It will be more or less random and  will be at thread shchdulers mercy.

Answer (score 2):

Your code suffers from the "lost notification" syndrome, which is alleviated (but not deterministically avoided) by the `sleep` call.

You haven't provided any mechanism which would ensure that, at the time of calling `exit`, all the threads have already reached their `wait` call. Therefore some threads will miss the notification and enter an eternal wait state.

The `notifyAll` call does wake up all waiting threads, but it doesn't wake up threads which enter the wait state in the future.

Answer (score 2):

With the following code:

```
t1.start();
t2.start();
t3.start();
```

You are starting the threads. Starting threads might take some time as it involves memory allocation and other operations. When your threads run they enter a *wait state*. Started threads do not, however, execute immediately. They start executing as soon as the scheduler decides it is time for them to execute. When you call `start` the main thread is currently running on the CPU. Without the `sleep` most likely the main thread will keep the CPU and call:

```
obj.exit();
```

Before the threads actually started, that is, before the threads actually entered the *wait state*. The `notifyAll` will execute in vain, as threads are not started yet and therefore are not waiting. The notification will be lost.

With the sleep call you are suspending the main thread for quite some time (for the CPU perspective). This means that the other threads will most likely get the CPU and enter the wait state. So when you then call `notifyAll` this time the notification will not get lost. Notice that there is no guarantee that this will happens: it might still happen that when you call `exit()` some (or all) other threads have not yet executed their `wait`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But i can see by log, all the three threads have executed wait() method. Also the second part is by invoking notifyAll() will all thread get the lock one by one?

Comment: I have no doubt that they called `wait`. But the question is: have they called `wait` before `notifyAll`? Also, when you call `notifyAll` **all** the threads waiting on the object will be awaken but they will need to compete again to acquire the lock on the object.